# Cross Region Replication for distributing data S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can we use cross region Replication to distribute data to 1000 of AWS account ? The data will be copied to thier S3 bucket and It will based on push model . As replication works on event.

Is there possibly limitations in this approach ? I know AWS doc does not specify thos approach.

Comment: Can you please tell us more about your use-case? For example _WHY_ would you want to replicate the data to thousands of AWS Accounts? Are they all _your_ accounts, or are they each owned by a different person? Why can't those accounts simply access a central bucket with the information? How much data are you wanting to replicate (quantity, GBs) and how often does the data update? The more you can tell us about your situation, the more likely we can provide a useful answer. Feel free to edit your question and add details instead of answering via a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by AWS S3 Replication. For one origin S3 bucket,  it can only replicate objects to one destination. [[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-add-config.html#replication-config-optional-dest-config)]

I don't think this is a good idea. Here are the reasons. Even if there is no limit to the number of AWS accounts that you can distribute your objects into, it's very likely that you will also hit other limits. For example, the source S3 bucket can only support 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per prefix, which is not enough for distributing objects to 1000 AWS accounts in near real-time. You probably will hit the size limit of the S3 resource policy as well in order to do cross-account replication.